# Substring with delimiters with Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new at Spark and Scala and I want to ask you a question :

I have a city field in my database (that I have already loaded it in a DataFrame) with this pattern : `"someLetters" + " - " + id + ')'.`
Example :

```
ABDCJ - 123456)   
AGDFHBAZPF - 1234567890)
```

The size of the field is not fixed and the `id` here can be an integer of 6 or 10 digits. So, what I want to do is to extract that `id` in a new column called `city_id`.
Concretely, I want to start by the last character of the digit which is ')', ignore it and extract the integer until I find a space. Then break.

I already tried to do this using `withColumn` or a `regex` or even `subString index` but I got confused since they are based on the index which I can't use here.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> start by the last character of the digit which is ')', ignore it and
>   extract the integer until I find a space

This can be done with regex pattern `.*?(\\d+)\\)$`, where `\\)$` matches the `)` at the end of the string, and then capture the digits with `\\d+`, and extract it as a new column; Notice `.*?` lazily (due to `?`) matches a string until the pattern `(\\d+)\\)$` is found:

```
df.withColumn("id", regexp_extract($"city", ".*?(\\d+)\\)$", 1)).show
+--------------------+----------+
|                city|        id|
+--------------------+----------+
|     ABDCJ - 123456)|    123456|
|AGDFHBAZPF - 1234...|1234567890|
+--------------------+----------+
```

Comment: there is a space before the id starts so you just use ````regexp_extract('cityid, """ (\d+)""",1)```` as well

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df=tempDF.withColumn("city_id",rtrim(element_at(split($"city"," - "),2),")"))
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. It said that it has too many arguments for rtrim method...

Comment: what version of spark do you have? rtrim with a trimString parameter was added in 2.3.0. before that, you can use substring and length. or the regexp_extract offered by @psidom (regexp_extract was added in v1.5.0)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the input is in the format in your example.
In order to get the number after the `-` without the trailing `)` you can execute the following command:

```
split(" - ")(1).dropRight(1)
```

The above split by the `-` sign and takes the second element (i.e. the number), and remove the last char (the `)`).

You can create `udf` which execute the above command, and create a new column using `withColumn` command

Comment: I tried your split method (embedeed in a "with column()" method but I failed... Can you show me the exact method please ? Do I have to use a map for example ? I am new at Scala. So excuse me for those errors

Answer (score 0):

I would go for regex_extract, but there are many alternatives : You can also do this using 2 splits :

```
df
.withColumn("id",
  split(
    split($"city"," - ")(1),"\\)"
  )(0) 
)
```

First, you split by `-` and take the  second element, then split by `)` and take the first element

Or another alternative, split by `-` and then drop `)` :

```
df
.withColumn("id",
   reverse(
     substring(         
       reverse(split($"city"," - ")(1)),
       2,
       Int.MaxValue
     )
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 regexp_replace functions also.

```
scala> val df = Seq(("ABDCJ - 123456)"),("AGDFHBAZPF - 1234567890)")).toDF("cityid")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [citiid: string]

scala> df.withColumn("id",regexp_replace(regexp_replace('cityid,""".*- """,""),"""\)""","")).show(false)
+------------------------+----------+
|cityid                  |id        |
+------------------------+----------+
|ABDCJ - 123456)         |123456    |
|AGDFHBAZPF - 1234567890)|1234567890|
+------------------------+----------+


scala>
```

Since the id seems to be an integer, you can cast it to long as

```
scala> val df2 = df.withColumn("id",regexp_replace(regexp_replace('cityid,""".*- """,""),"""\)""","").cast("long"))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [cityid: string, id: bigint]

scala> df2.show(false)
+------------------------+----------+
|cityid                  |id        |
+------------------------+----------+
|ABDCJ - 123456)         |123456    |
|AGDFHBAZPF - 1234567890)|1234567890|
+------------------------+----------+


scala> df2.printSchema
root
 |-- cityid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)


scala>
```